# HP G61 laptop wont boot- display stays off, caps and num lock indicators blink repeatedly

Tags: boot, laptop

I had my HP G61 laptop running in sleep for a while. When I came back to it about a half-hour later, it was no longer in sleep mode - the power light and the Wi-Fi indicator light were on (I keep Wi-Fi off becuase I use a wired connection) - but nothing was showing on screen. In fact, the display wasn't even turned on. So I let it sit for about 10 minutes but nothing happened.

I did a force shut down and rebooted. Instead of a normal boot, the display didnt turn on, the Wi-Fi indicator was off, and the Caps Lock and Num Lock lights just blinked repeatedly. On the external keyboard i use, none of the light indicators were blinking or even on. I tried force shut-down again 10 times, then unplugged all connections except for the power cable (my laptop battery dosent hold a charge for more than 2 minutes, so I always must have a wall connection) and tried to boot again but still nothing happened. I unplugged the battery and even then nothing happened. I also tried booting with the disk drive open, and then with it closed again. On the time it was closed, I was able to successfully boot into Windows, but recieved a "Windows did not shut-down sucessfully" notice. Does anybody know why this may have happened?

My PC's specs:

- Windows 7 Home Premium, 64-bit
- 4GB of physical RAM, 8GB of vRAM (on a flash drive)
- AMD Vision x64 processor (don't know any other specs about it)
- ATI Radeon graphics card, 392 MB
- DVD-R/W lightscribe drive
- 2 External hard-disks (first one is 1.5TB, second one is 1TB)
- custom boot-screen and boot-annimation
- Standard BIOS

apps running before sleep:

- firefox 10.4
- itunes 10.6
- adobe photoshop extended CS5.1
- rockstar games social club (running in background)
- microsoft powerpoint 2010 professional edition
- google chrome

I was NOT running Aero or any fancy themes - I was using the normal windows classic theme. I have a desktop icon manager application called Stardock Fences that was also running (it runs as a service/process).

Answer (score 2):

So your computer works but you're wondering what the blinking lights meant?
Here's a link to their meaning and a troubleshooting/resolution guide:
[Link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01443366&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after reading and research it seems too be a common problem or a possible design flaw with HP.

My fix and a simple one after days of research and trying all possibilities, pull out main battery and keep it out, plug in your power cord, turn power on and let it sit for few hours, this apparently recharges internal battery that wears out from letting labtop sit idle or in sleep mode to much causing it to drain or just replace it with new battery, and voila rebooted, screen came back on and computer has ran fine since.